# tailwindcss 3 is not loading css in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss

i have been using tailwindcss 2 but i wanted to upgrade to 3. I followed their tutorial but is not working i dont know why.

`tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {

    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

`postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

`index.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

`index.css` is imported in `index.tsx.`

`index.tsx` file

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './redux/store';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@dicebear/avatars": "^4.8.5",
    "@dicebear/avatars-avataaars-sprites": "^4.8.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.15",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-canvas-confetti": "^1.2.1",
    "react-cookie": "^4.0.3",
    "react-countdown-circle-timer": "^2.5.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.4",
    "react-window": "^1.8.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.19",
    "@types/numeral": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.18",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
    "@types/react-select": "^4.0.17",
    "@types/react-window": "^1.8.5",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/tailwindcss": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^6.5.1",
    "cypress": "^8.3.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.7"
  }
}
```

`Text.jsx`

```
const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div className='flex text-green-500'>
      <h1>Text Green</h1>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Test
```

[image]

Comment: try replacing your config content string to this = ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, you need to update react-scripts to the latest update
`npm install react-scripts@latest`

Comment: I had the same issue. Tailwind first worked, but then stopped.
I installed react-scripts@latest but nothing changed. I fixed it with deleting `@tailwind base; ...` in the global stylesheet and then added it back. Weird bug but maybe it could help somebody

Comment: Updating latest version of react-scripts didn't work for me . I previously had 5.0.0, then when I ran that command to get latest, it changed to ^5.0.0. Removing and re-adding the tailwind directive `@tailwind base;` also didn't work. My index.html references `/dist/main.css`. When I view `/dist/main.css` in the Chrome browser, I don't see the CSS that I can see in Visual Studio. What I see is the html for index.html. Are there any other solutions? thanks.